# Raphael JS and Text positioning?

Tags: javascript, svg, raphael

I'm trying to position text within the SVG canvas, by supplying **x, y coordinates**

```
var t = paper.text(50, 50, "Raphaël\nkicks\nbutt!");
```

but does not position the text like all other objects...

**x, y coordinates specify the center** of the object! **Not the *"left and top most"* pixel!**

---

I would like to ***"left align"*** the text along a line, same as standard HTML.

Help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Resolved!

By using the following

```
paper.print(100, 100, "Test string", paper.getFont("Times", 800), 30);
```

it now aligns text on the left.

Comment: paper.print() is not the same as paper.text() because print() returns a set of objects where each object is a path resembling a character. See @dasha salo's answer for the correct "text" solution. Unfortunately there is no vertical alignment property currently.

Answer (score 151):

Text-anchor property for text method is set to 'middle' by default.

If you want to left align it then change text-anchor in attributes for the object:

```
var t = paper.text(50, 50, "Raphaël\nkicks\nbutt!").attr({'text-anchor': 'start'});
```

Comment: Probably the 4th time for me to look this question up and get your answer. First to upvote. ;)

Comment: but is there a top anchor?

Answer (score 20):

I know you didn't say you need to vertical align it to top, but if you want to use paper.text instead of paper.print... and would like to vertical align to be top.

Try this:

```
function alignTop(t) {
    var b = t.getBBox();
    var h = Math.abs(b.y2) - Math.abs(b.y) + 1;

    t.attr({
        'y': b.y + h
    });
}
```

And just pass the Raphael text object to it.  It will top align it for you.
and just call that function

Comment: As You said @RadiantHex didn't ask for vertical align, but at least it helped me, thanks!

Comment: Thank you good sir for the t.attr({y:}) reference, you saved my butt! :)

Answer (score 0):

Following code works well in IE , Chrome (Firefox not tested):

```
var t = paper.text(50, 50, "Raphaël\nkicks\nbutt!"),
    b = t._getBBox();
t.translate(-b.width/2,-b.height/2);
```

**Explanation:**

in Raphael , text is centered around your given x & y by default, you can set left align with:

```
t.attr({'text-anchor':'start'})
```

but you have no attribute to set it top align. I firstly tried :

```
var b=t.getBBox();
```

but it returned NaN in IE, so I turned to:

```
var b=t._getBBox();
```

_getBBox() is undocumented but used internally by Raphael itself , and it works!

Hope it helps.